# Is this algebraic deduction true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Since $v_{1}^2 - 2v_1v_2 + v_{2}^2 > 0$ because $(v_{1} - v_{2})^2 > 0$, and
since $v_{1}^2 + 2v_1v_2 + v_{2}^2 > 0$ because $(v_{1} + v_{2})^2 > 0$.

Can we deduce that $v_{1}^2 - v_1v_2 + v_{2}^2 > 0$ because $(v_{1} - v_{2})^2$ $<$ $(v_{1}^2 - v_1v_2 + v_{2}^2)$ $<$ $(v_{1} + v_{2})^2$, for every real number $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$.

Comment: I guess you mean $v_1^2 - v_1 v_2 + v_2^2 \geq 0$ for every real $v_1, v_2$ ($\geq$ instead of $>$) because otherwise your inequality is wrong for $v_1 = 0, v_2 = 0$.

Comment: In the last expression, if $v_2 \lt 0,$ and $v_1 \geq 0$, then $(v_1+v_2)^2 \lt (v_1-v_2)^2$

Comment: The basic idea is correct. As SampleTime mentioned you need to fix the < and > to $\le$ and $\ge$. And as amWhy mentions, you need to consider the inequality switching around when $v_1v_2<0$ as opposed to $v_1v_2>0$. $v_1^2-v_1v_2+v_2^2$ remains in the middle so you can still conclude it is $\ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

The deduction is wrong: set $v_2 = -v_1$ your last inequality

$$
(v_1 - v_2)^2 < (v_1^2 - v_1 v_2 + v_2^2) < (v_1 + v_2)^2 
$$

becomes

$$
4 v_1^2 < 3 v_1^2 < 0
$$

which is obviously wrong even if you replace the "$<$" signs with "$\leq$" signs.

You can instead rewrite your expression:

$$
v_1^2 - v_1 v_2 + v_2^2 = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -0.5 \\ -0.5 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

The matrix is positive definite so $v_1^2 - v_1 v_2 + v_2^2 > 0$ if $v_1 \neq 0, v_2 \neq 0$.